# Java multi-threading race-condition on a shared char array

Tags: java, multithreading, java-memory-model

Suppose I have the following:

```
char[] shared = new char[]{'a', 'b'};
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
Future<?> f1 = exec.submit(() -> shared[0] = 'A');
Future<?> f2 = exec.submit(() -> shared[1] = 'B');
f1.get(); f2.get();
System.out.println(shared);
```

I expect this will usually print:

```
'AB'
```

But is it also possible for this to print:

```
'aB'
```

or

```
'bA'
```

I'm wondering if since `shared` is not volatile, one thread might, while saving its changes to its corresponding char element, save its neighboring byte(s), which is stale in its local processor cache, and stomp over the changes made by another thread. I have a feeling the answer to this is "no", because I think it would violate Java's Memory Model which says that whenever a thread is joined, all the actions it's done happen-before the join. But if that's the case, then I'm curious how that's prevented? My understanding is that when bytes are flushed the entire cache-line gets flushed, and I'd imagine a char[] array would have multiple elements sitting in the same cache-line.

Comment: I think you meant `shared[0]` and `shared[1]` instead of `char[0]` and `char[1]`?

Comment: Woops. Fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This has been specified in the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.6) exactly:

> #### 17.6. Word Tearing
>
> One consideration for implementations of the Java Virtual Machine is that every field and array element is considered distinct; updates to one field or element must not interact with reads or updates of any other field or element. In particular, two threads that update adjacent elements of a byte array separately must not interfere or interact and do not need synchronization to ensure sequential consistency.
>
> Some processors do not provide the ability to write to a single byte. It would be illegal to implement byte array updates on such a processor by simply reading an entire word, updating the appropriate byte, and then writing the entire word back to memory. This problem is sometimes known as word tearing, and on processors that cannot easily update a single byte in isolation some other approach will be required.

In the worst case, that would imply performing such array updates with a CAS instruction or similar, to ensure that no in-between update happened. But as far as I know, the x86/x64 architecture is not affected by this, as it has instructions to modify items of smaller size and it will handle invalidating the other CPU core’s cache line to ensure that the other CPU cores will fetch the changed data before performing their own update. Of course, this still is slower than two CPU cores performing updates on different cache lines.